Why contour with constant imaginary part implies rapid change in real part
In the method of steepest descent, considering integrals of the type
$$J(z)=\int_{C}e^{zf(t)}dt$$
where contour $C$ is such that the integrand goes to zeros at the ends of the contour, the method relies on finding the saddle point where the imaginary part of the integrand, $\text{Im}[zf(t)]$, is constant. Morse and Feshbach (p. 440) state that the significance of choosing this path is because, when the imaginary part is constant for an analytical function, the real part will change rapidly. The book refers this fact as a result of having the real and imaginary parts ($u+iv$) for analytical function $f(z)$ in general being related by (see p. 371 in same book):
$$u(\xi,\eta)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{(x-\xi)v(x,0)}{(x-\xi)^{2}+\eta^{2}}dx$$
$$v(\xi,\eta)=\frac{-1}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{(x-\xi)u(x,0)}{(x-\xi)^{2}+\eta^{2}}
dx$$
But it is not immediately clear to me why are these relations between $u$ and $v$ implying that choosing a path with constant imaginary part will yield maximal change in real part?
Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

Maybe by making connection with Kramers-Kronig relations ?
